# How convert SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color to System.Drawing.Color?

Tags: c#, converters, system.drawing, imagesharp

I need to convert instance of `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color` to `System.Drawing.Color` and backwards. How to do it?

Comment: You should better refer to SixLabors docs. It seems both classes have argb methods, so you could use argb to convert

Answer (score 2):

Just added extensions:

```cs
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
    public static class ColorExtensions
    {
        public static System.Drawing.Color ToSystemDrawingColor(this SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color c){
            var converted = c.ToPixel<Argb32>();
            return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int)converted.Argb);
        }
        public static SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color ToImageSharpColor(this System.Drawing.Color c){
            return SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color.FromRgba(c.R,c.G,c.B,c.A);
        }
    }
```